# Django Custom Filters using templatetags method isn't working! Exception Value is : Invalid filter: 'dict_'

Tags: python, django, filter, django-templates

I have the following structure for the Django application.

Was actually sending "dict-data" for rendering to the template file, where one of the field-key in the dict starts with "_id". Django template cannot retrieve the underscore key-value, so using custom filter to achieve this. [Using this file in the templatetags folder https://github.com/halfnibble/django-underscore-filters/blob/master/underscore_filters/templatetags/underscore_tags.py]

```
.
├── configure.py
├── manage.py
├── static
└── app_name
    ├── abc
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── xyz
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── templates
    ├── templatetags
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── underscore_filters.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── utils.py
    ├── views.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

When using  in the template file as  {{ mycustomdict|dict_:'_id' }}, I was getting error. [using  {% load underscore_filters } to load the custom filter  ]

```
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid filter: 'dict_'
Exception Location: /home/satish/env/django/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py in find_filter, line 430
Python Executable:  /home/satish/env/django/bin/python
```

I think filters in the templatetags folder are not loading. Any help to solve this would be so great!

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The templatetags directory needs to be inside an app, and that app needs to be added to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Hi Daniel,

Actually, templatetags is placed inside the xyz folder only,  was checking all the possibilities and kept in the project-folder. [Added in INSTALLED_APPS also.]

Its not working that way even!! What could be the steps to understand why filter is not loading?